# Put HTML content in errordlg/msgbox

Tags: matlab

It is possible to put HTML content in the text of the errodlg/msgbox in matlab? I know the "latex" interpreter option, that makes possible to show latex content, but i need to show a hyperlink to the user in the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible, as text labels do not support HTML.

You can create your own dialog using `dialog`, and then either use a little [undocumented functionality](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-matlab-labels/) to put a Java label on there, or perhaps more simply you can just display the URL as text, and have a button saying "visit URL", with a callback function that calls the `web` command.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperlink text is still not supported in Matlab msgbox() nor in uialert() but you can set it up within an independent figure without a latex interpreter.

Here's a demo that adds a blue text to a uifigure that, when clicked, opens a webpage (via a ButtonDownFcn callback function). 
The "OK" button will close the figure.

```
% Create message box figure & axes
uifig = uifigure(); 
uiax = uiaxes(uifig,'Position',[0 0 uifig.Position(3:4)]); 
axis(uiax,'off')
% Add hyperlink text
% You don't need Latex interpreter if you're not underlining the link.
th = text(uiax, .5, .3, '\underline{mathworks.com}',...
    'color',[0 0 .8],'FontSize',20,'Interpreter','latex',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','center'); 
th.ButtonDownFcn = @(~,~)web('mathworks.com'); % this opens the website
% Add OK button that closes figure
uibutton(uifig,'Text','Ok','Position',...
    [50,50,75,30],'ButtonPushedFcn',@(h,~)delete(h.Parent))
```